# Is it unmount /dev/sdb or /dev/sdb1

Tags: unmount

Do these have the same effect when the drive has only one big partition?

```
udisks --unmount /dev/sdb

udisks --unmount /dev/sdb1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well --- it depends. Basically, it depends on if the device is partitioned or not (used whole). If it has just one big partition, it's partitioned anyway.

I have a device (a Garmin GPS) that looks like an unpartioned disk, look (from the command `mount` which shows the mounted devices):

```
/dev/sdc on /media/romano/GARMIN type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1153,gid=1001,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
```

so this disk needs to be unmounted with `umount /dev/sdc`.

Notice however that this is a bad thing in general, stemming from the age of floppy disks --- if you still have one of those, they were mostly unpartitioned. Devices should be partitioned, even if they have just one big  partition. Otherwise a lot of things  expecting it will not automount the thing --- it happens randomly on Trusty with my Garmin, too.

A normal disk when mounted look like this:

```
/dev/sdd1 on /media/romano/I2MTC15_RG type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1153,gid=1001,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
```

so it has to be unmounted with `umount /dev/sdd1`.

Anyway, getting it wrong will just throw an error...

```
[romano:~] % umount /dev/sdd 
umount: /dev/sdd is not mounted (according to mtab)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can unmount only a partition, not a disk. So it is `/dev/sdb1`.

You can do it by

```
umount /dev/sdb1
```

too.

Comment: That's not really true.  There's nothing to stop you from doing `mkfs /dev/sdb` (don't try if there is anything important on the disk) and then you'll be able to `mount /dev/sdb` and unmount it too.  People *usually* use partitions for filesystems, but the whole disk device can be used too.  It's more common on "small" devices like flash drives, CD-R or DVD-R, etc.

Comment: @NateEldredge Well --- if you `mkfs` the whole disk you will not have any partition left ;-) --- so this answer is tersely correct for a device "with one big partition" as the OP is asking.